# Change default font size for Mono programs?

Tags: fonts, mono

I have a couple of programs I use occasionally that use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) (Cross-platform version of MS .NET). The fonts in these programs are always far too small, much like the default in Wine. Unlike Wine though there isn’t any obvious way of changing them. Can it be done?

[image: Mono vs. GTK]

Comment: Try this: http://www.vakuumverpackt.de/configurablesystemfontsformono/ Also good to know how to change font size in monodevelop menus and dialogs.

Comment: URL does not work anymore :(